# Young cherry tree pruning

Tags: pruning, cherries

I bought this young cherry tree last year and it was about half the size. It was pruned when I bought it (imagine1) you can see where the cut was made.
It did not start growing from the sides but rather from exactly where it was pruned. Now I have a tree that’s tall and leggy, scared it will break with winds.

Can you tell me where to prune it as it’s all one sided right now.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Train the side branches to grow more horizontally.  This makes the center more airy, all the branches get more sun, and the crotch angles become closer to 90 degrees, which makes it less likely to get a splitting break.  You can use weights or tie them down with bricks or stakes.  Also shorten the central leader to encourage new shoots.  Where to cut?  A bit above where you want new branches to emerge.  Have some fun watching fruit tree training videos.

Comment: Here's a nice one: https://youtu.be/sLZQ7nb0g5A By the way the 90 degree angle is more for apples, apparently.  For cherries apparently 30 to 60 degrees is best because with 90 degrees the branch might break with the weight of the fruit.